# Store Procedure Two different database and join help

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures, mysql-5.6

I try to write store procedure that ı have a question.Firstly I have two db in same local server.One of them is hfcenta_test db has agency old datas and it has country code column with country name.Now I have different db and ı have coursesystemdb that has country data but it has country_ıd column and ı have countries tables extra. I want to old tables data transferred according to new agencies table in different db.

At the picture ı tried some things and achieved two tables combined. But how to update old db tables according to new db agency table ?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LKWx.png)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am working one MySql Server

Comment: Excess tag is removed.

Comment: The pictures are not useful. Replace them with table structures (as CREATE TABLE scripts), source data for old table and countries table (as INSERT INTO scripts, 5-10 rows enough) and show desired new table state as table-formatted text.

Comment: "Two db" -- Two DATABASEs in a single instance of MySQL?  Or 2 instances of MySQL?  You want to say `FROM db1.tableA JOIN db2.tableB ON ...`?

Comment: Yes exactly thats right

Comment: But probably ı should use right join cause old  table stay for example db1.tableA and compare one table in db2.tableB and update one table column in another table of db2 table